# How to block another domain to access and get result from my website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

Another domain is showing duplicate content of my website (all pages)
When I entered this domain I see my site content.

If I change something on my site, I see it immediately on the another domain.

I think he's using some function `fopen` or `curl` or something else to show my content immediately from my website

How do I block it?

*my server: cpanel, php5

Comment: check logs and block request from that domain/ip?

Comment: Other website might be using a proxy.

Comment: looking `referer` is an option but can be spoofed, and i think cannot be done at all

Comment: Post the d-bags website on 4chan and see if you can get them to do a ddos...

Comment: Check the access log. Do you see a particular script that access your site daily or in an interval? Does you site publish a RSS or ATOM feed? Can you share the information here?

Comment: It could be interesting to know who is the douchebag site also

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Check this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/388515/htaccess-blocking-proxy

Comment: Get a lawyer, sue him.

Answer (score 3):

You can use their IP address to serve them a 404 page. Or if you really want to be clever. For just their IP address serve wrong or embarrassing information that looks similar but is not the good content.

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "12.1.3.5"){ //banned IP

    //do something else

}
```

Comment: What I do when he change the ip ?

Comment: You rewrite the script for the new IP?

Comment: You can write a cron job to regularly check the ip for the website and store it in a database of sorts and just do whatever you want with those specific IP's. I say troll them all to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the user agent if it is not a browser Firefox , safari ...Deny accessing this will freak out the other domain that is copying your pages example:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE){
//Internet Explorer Good
}else{
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE){
//FireFox Good
}else{
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE){
//Chrome Good
}else{
//Check for safari , Opera , AndroidBrowser and IOS browser , Internet Explorer Mobile and text phones
//else run this code
die("Acessing this site is only allowed from this domain example.com"); 
}
}
}
```

EDIT:

append this code to your .htaccess

```
BrowserMatchNoCase SpammerRobot bad_bot
BrowserMatchNoCase SecurityHoleRobot bad_bot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

As people have said in comment the user agent is empty:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
die("Error");
}
```

You could also apply the ip address so it will be harder for the other domain to break you:

You can also check for the UserOperating system but it is not required as it will may cause problem for some users so just don't do it but it still a good idea.

keep me UpToDate for any help

Comment: Why don t you use else if instead of else{if} ?

Comment: user agent is empty from this domain